# Happy Birthday to Us

Tags: discussion

Happy Birthday to Us!

We've [been around for 2 years](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce) and what a great 2 years it's been!

[image: Brithday Cake]

Comment: Happy 2 yrs SFSE & wish u many more yrs :-)

Comment: Oh no, now we are in the terrible twos!  Watch out for temper tantrums.  :)

Comment: Amazing effort everyone. We got further than we expected I reckon. Keep up the great job!

Comment: This community has shown great potential.We have helped lot of people and we have gained so much..Happy birthday stackexchange salesforce

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For posterity (3 days late).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting these stats Daniel. Perhaps the question we need to ask ourselves once we're done celebrating is how do we improve at "Answered" and "Answer Ratio" or what's inhibiting us from having performed better in those two areas? Awesome the way we outperformed expectations everywhere else! :)

Comment: @crmprogdev I think those target ratios were about having an active beta when there weren't many people on the site. IMHO, despite the beta in the Sites name, we aren't really in the beta scale any more. Keeping those ratios as the Site grows in usage would be tough. Would be interesting to compare stats with a larger non-beta StackExchange site.

Comment: Answer Ratio has never concerned me too much, one accepted correct answer is better than one good and one debatable! Thanks to all of you for getting behind this and making the site such a success!

Comment: Agreed on Answer Ratio. Not certain there's ever going to be an acceptable or "good" answer to some of what's asked here either. LOL! ;)